# Is it possible to alter the SELECT/WHERE of jOOQ DSL query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I would like manipulate a jOOQ DSL query changing its *SELECT* columns and *WHERE* conditions.

For example:

```
DSLContext ctx = ...;
SelectHavingStep query = ctx.select(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP, DSL.count(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP))
   .from(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY)
   .where(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ID.gt("P"))
   .groupBy(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP);
```

*Use case 1:*

I would like to pass the above query to a utility class that will produce the same query just with with a different SELECT, for example:

```
ctx.select(DSL.count())
   .from(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY)
   .where(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ID.gt("P"))
   .groupBy(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP);
```

This particular example is to be able to create paginated results showing the total number of rows of the query.

Use case 2:

I would like to pass the above query to a utility class that will produce the same query just with with a modified WHERE clause, for example:

```
SelectHavingStep query = 
  ctx.select(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP, DSL.count(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP))
     .from(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY)
     .where(
        MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ID.gt("P")
        .and(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP.in("100", "200", "300"))
      )
     .groupBy(MyEntity.MY_ENTITY.ZIP);
```

This particular example is to further restrict a query based on some criteria (i.e. data visibility based on the user doing the query).

Is this possible?

Currently I'm using helper classes to do this at query construction time in the application code. I would like to move the responsibility to a library so it can be enforced transparently to the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to alter jOOQ objects, instead you should try to create them dynamically in a functional way. There are different ways to achieve your use-cases, e.g.

#### Use case 1:

An approach to generic paginated querying can be seen here: https://blog.jooq.org/calculating-pagination-metadata-without-extra-roundtrips-in-sql/

Ideally, you would avoid the extra round trip for the `COUNT(*)` query and use a `COUNT(*) OVER ()` window function. If that's not available in your SQL dialect, then you could do this, instead:

```java
public ResultQuery<Record> mySelect(
    boolean count,
    Supplier<List<Field<?>>> select,
    Function<? super SelectFromStep<Record>, ? extends ResultQuery<Record>> f
) {
    return f.apply(count ? ctx.select(count()) : ctx.select(select.get()));
}
```

And then use it like this:

```java
mySelect(false, 
    () -> List.of(MY_ENTITY.ZIP),
    q -> q.from(MY_ENTITY)
          .where(MY_ENTITY.ID.gt("P"))
          .groupBy(MY_ENTITY.ZIP)
).fetch();
```

This is just one way to do it. There are many others, see the below link.

#### Use case 2:

Just take the above example one step further and extract the logic used to create the `WHERE` clause in yet another function, e.g.

```java
public Condition myWhere(Function<? super Condition, ? extends Condition> f) {
    return f.apply(MY_ENTITY.ID.gt("P"));
}
```

And now use it as follows:

```java
mySelect(false, 
    () -> List.of(MY_ENTITY.ZIP),
    q -> q.from(MY_ENTITY)
          .where(myWhere(c -> c.and(MY_ENTITY.ZIP.in("100", "200", "300")))
          .groupBy(MY_ENTITY.ZIP)
).fetch();
```

Again, there are many different ways to solve this, depending on what is the "common part", and what is the "user-defined part". You can also abstract over your `MY_ENTITY` table and pass around functions that produce the actual table.

#### More information

See also these resources:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/
- https://blog.jooq.org/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/

Comment: Lukas, thanks for your prompt reply.

Currently I'm doing something similar to what you are suggesting, using a command pattern that provides wrapper functions (for the condition) and enforces the wrapper is being called. 

My idea was to do it after the fact (after query is being created) to reduce the chance of a developer error misplacing the wrapper at the wrong place.

Thanks again.

Comment: @AlejandroAbdelnur: Well, you can always use the "classic" model API via `DSLContext.selectQuery()`, which produces an (append only) mutable object. I generally don't recommend it, because: 1) It will be removed in the (very) long run, 2) it's far less elegant than an FP approach.

Comment: I have a case where a helper function would want to add both a JOIN clause and a WHERE clause item, and I don't want the caller to have tow worry about this, I just want to apply the logic  that causes the insertion of these two levels of items into the query tree.  So there are use cases where dynamic query aren't a friendly path when you are trying to eliminate redundant code and a chance of error.